# Creating a buffer round a polyline

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, buffer

At the moment the code I use creates a buffer extending 1000km from each geometry creating square buffer zones over polygons, lines and points. How can I amend the code so that it creates a 'sausage' buffer around the polyline instead of creating a square extent? Should I create another variable for biggerExtent?

This is the polyline current code which I need to amend from the others:

```
if (geometry.type === "polygon" || geometry.type === "multipoint" || geometry.type === "polyline") {
        var searchExtent = geometry.getExtent();
        var biggerExtent = new esri.geometry.Extent(searchExtent.xmin - 1000, searchExtent.ymin - 1000, searchExtent.xmax + 1000, searchExtent.ymax + 1000, new esri.SpatialReference({
                    wkid : 27700
                }));
        graphic1 = new esri.Graphic(biggerExtent, buffersymbol);
        buffergraphicsLayer.add(graphic1);
        bufferExtent = getBufferExtent();
        graphic2 = new esri.Graphic(bufferExtent, bufferextentsymbol);
        buffergraphicsLayer.add(graphic2);
```

Comment: I don't know anything about javascript, but you are getting what you asked for - an extent object. The min/max extent of the input data.. There must be another tool / method to do an actual "buffer" of the geometry itself.

Comment: I see what you mean - I need to isolate the polyline and use a different function with it...

Comment: The easiest way is to use the buffer method of a geometryservice, samples are here: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/#search/BufferParameters